# PSQL =ANY works but in condition giving error when sending dynamic array from nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I am sending a dynamic array from nodejs to Postgres. The `=ANY` clause works but `IN` clause gives and error. Can anyone help why this is happening and what is the best way to do this.

This code is  working fine

```
let arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
 await getDetails(arr);

const getDetails = async (arr) => {
    const detail = await db.any(`
        SELECT
        *
        from table 
        where key = ANY($1::text[])
    `, [arr]);
    return detail
}
```

But this is giving error

```
let arr = ['a','b','c','d'];
 await getDetails(arr);

const getDetails = async (arr) => {
    const detail = await db.any(`
        SELECT
        *
        from table 
        where key IN ($1::text[])
    `, [arr]);
    return detail
}
```

type of key in table is Text.

i am expecting table to return all the rows that have Key present in the array.

Comment: IN can't be used with an array. You will have to use `= any()`

Comment: but when i work with psql , it works 
`select * from table where key in(
  'a', 'b','c', 'd'
) `

Comment: A list of values is something different than an array  `IN ('a','b')` is not the same as  `=any(array['a','b'])`

Comment: thankyou for telling me this.